# java.lang.IllegalStateException Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite

I m getting the following error in the google play console, and no idea how to solve it. I don't use SQLite in my app. The error started appearing after targeting SDK 30. Upgrading libraries to the latest has not helped.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run (ForceStopRunnable.java:128)
  at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run (SerialExecutor.java:91)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: 
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen (Native Method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open (SQLiteConnection.java:214)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open (SQLiteConnection.java:198)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner (SQLiteDatabase.java:838)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open (SQLiteDatabase.java:823)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase (SQLiteDatabase.java:716)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase (ContextImpl.java:664)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase (ContextWrapper.java:289)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:145)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction (RoomDatabase.java:476)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction (RoomDatabase.java:281)
  at androidx.work.impl.model.SystemIdInfoDao_Impl.getWorkSpecIds (SystemIdInfoDao_Impl.java:120)
  at androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobScheduler.reconcileJobs (SystemJobScheduler.java:298)
  at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.cleanUp (ForceStopRunnable.java:249)
  at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.forceStopRunnable (ForceStopRunn
```

Comment: Maybe you don't use sqlite but some of your dependencies are. Also you have Room in stacktrace so this is also a lead. You need to be more specific.

Comment: This is coming from `WorkManager` (`androidx.work`). Make sure that you are on the latest version of that dependency.

Comment: Targeting SDK 30 means you are now working on Android 11. Android 11 limits the access to files on the device, I assume that maybe a library you are using or something piece of code is probably trying to access a path which is no longer valid in this Android version.

Comment: Can you please add a list of all your project dependencies with their versions to the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this is still an open issue with androidx.work but should soon be fixed.
You can follow the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179160707

Make sure to enable notifications: [image: Enabling notifications in issuetracker]